# Get rows from other file and filter them

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2016

I have some excel files arranged like this: (Im using MS Excel 2016)

```
folder/
  Master.xlsx (has column `Category` with value A, B or C)
  SlaveA.xlsx
  SlaveB.xlsx
  SlaveC.xlsx
```

They are located on network drive. I want to make Slaves to fetch data from Master.xlsx and filter to display only their own category. It seems not to be a big deal, but when i tried to resolve it by outside file reference it isn't working correctly ( something like `PATH/filse.xlsx!Table1[@[Category]]` ).

1. The reference works only when i have already opened te source file (Master.xlsx) otherwise it returns error that cant load refenrece file.
2. All files are password protected, so when i correctly run everything (First open Master.xlsx and after that Slave.xlsx), Slave data will update, but filters aren`t refreshing. I must then type password and refresh them manually.

This is really problematic. It would be also nice if there is a way to move Slave's out of their folder. Meaby there is a better way to do this. I want only to display data from excel filtered by specefied category.

Comment: Do you use VBA, C#, or what?

Comment: @z32a7ul Im using MS Excel 2016 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to create updates from a password-protected file the way you are suggesting. Excel passwords encrypt elements of the worksheets, which will leave them uninterpretable without the password.

Your options are to un-protect the source file, to manually type in the password, or to create a macro that will do this for you.  (You might be able to use VBA within Excel to do this, but as that would require one Excel file to open and type in the password for another Excel file, you would probably be better off using a regular Windows macro editor).

Comment: And what in case, when the files wont be password protected? When i try to do the same thing they also must be open, otherwise i get address error